# How do I get permission to delete rows in Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using this script:

```
function enterData(data) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow()
  if(data == "" || data == "-"){
    sheet.deleteRow(row)
  } else {
    return data;
  }
}
```

I am attempting to delete a row if a certain cell is empty, and it seems to work just fine except for the fact that it won't allow to actually delete the row.

[image: Error Message]

I run my function through a cell by using `=enterData(whatever_cell_i_choose)`. I've read that custom functions have limits to what they can do, but I can't seem to find any other way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error images shows that you are using your code as a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions). They are only allowed to return a single value or an array of values. They are not allowed to do any action that change that requires authorization like deleting a row, so, it's not possible to get permission to delete a row for your custom function. Instead use menu, or an installable trigger to run it.