# How to write a function to Count number of sheets inside other spreadsheets by referencing the URL

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to count the number of sheets (tabs) inside a workbook by referencing that workbooks URL. For example:
workbook 1 is the master tracking workbook
workbook 2 has 3 sheets (tabs)

- Cell A2 in workbook 1 contains workbook 2 URL
- Cell B2 in workbook 1 =countsheets(A2)
- Cell B2 in workbook 1 result is the number 3

I could repeat this script for each row in the sheet. A3's link would actually give the number of sheets result in B3, A4's link would give the result in B4, ect.

The following code I did is not worked out:

```
function countsheets() {
 var app = SpreadsheetApp;
 var workbook1 = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var s = workbook1.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
 var url = s.getRange('A2').getValue();
 var workbook2 = app.openByUrl(url);
 var numOfSheets = workbook2.getSheets().length;
 s.getRange('B2').setValue(numOfSheets);
};
```

Help me !!! Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That snippet would require user authorization to access other spreadsheets, but custom functions [cannot include services that require authorization](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services).

Among the [alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40011381/3751868), you can create a menu item to do that. For example, considering that column A has URLs and column B should have the number of sheets, you can do the following:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('Special Functions')
    .addItem('Count sheets', 'countSheets')
    .addToUi();
}

function countSheets() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const urls = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().flat().filter(String);
  const numSheets = [];
  for (const url of urls) {
    numSheets.push([
      SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url).getSheets().length
    ]);
  }
  sheet.getRange(2, 2, numSheets.length).setValues(numSheets);
};
```

Comment: Many thanks. But it's cause the errors:  “Exception: Invalid argument: url”?" I don't know why? :(

Comment: That usually happens if you pass an invalid URL to `openByUrl()`, so try to add a `Logger.log(url)` inside the FOR loop so you can see what URL is the problem.

Comment: Oh, I've tried again. It's working out!!! Column URL is a mix of folders and sheets. Thanks again (Y) mshcruz